# Image embedded with Pandas to_html does not appear in email message

Tags: python, html, pandas, email, html-email

I have an image on a local drive with its source path (in HTML) saved in a Pandas dataframe (i.e., read from test.dat). The dataframe is then converted to HTML and sent as an email message, but the embedded image does not appear in the email as given in the screenshot. The MWE is given below. What changes are required such that image is successfully embedded?

**test.dat**

```
A   B   C   D   E   F
John    Doe 75.95   0.2 0.4 <img src="/home/tom/pictures/test.png" width="60" >
```

[image]

**MWE**

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr


#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Sender and recipient details
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
fromaddr = 'abc@xyz.com'
password = 'password'
toaddr = 'xyz@abc.com'


#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Compile message
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
msg = EmailMessage()                                                                            # Instance of MIMEMultipart
msg['From'] = formataddr((str(Header('John Doe', 'utf-8')), fromaddr))                      # Storing the senders email address
msg['To'] = toaddr                                                                              # Storing the receivers email address 
msg['Subject'] = 'Test' # Storing the subject 
msg.set_content('Test message')
msg_html = '<html><h1><span style="font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif">' + \
    '<span style="color:#000000"><strong>Test message</strong></span></span></h1>'
data = pd.read_csv('test.dat', \
                            delimiter='\t', comment = '#')
data = data.to_html(index = True, escape=False).replace('<td>', '<td align="left">')
msg_html += data
msg.add_alternative(msg_html,subtype = 'html')
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)                                                            # Creates SMTpayload session
server.starttls()                                                                                       # Start TLS for security
server.login(fromaddr, password)                                                                        # Authentication
server.send_message(msg)                                                                 # Send the mail
server.quit()
```

Comment: You could load the images in base64 format, check [this example](https://gist.github.com/stas-sl/3f8e14de912bb738d808d1aa0838df5c)

Comment: Base64 doesn't have good support: https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/. You'll need to upload the image first, and reference the full URL

Comment: @RJAdriaansen The example does the job partially. I am able to view the image via Thunderbird, but on Gmail it appears blank.

Comment: Yes, check the link in @Nathan's comment - it is not supported by gmail. So if you want to use it with gmail you would indeed need to upload the images somewhere and then wrap the urls in `img` tags.